# Why does python in while loop returns bigger value first even tho first one is supposed to be left pointer which can be only smaller

Tags: python

Hi so I did leetcode quesiton Two Sum II (Find two values in a sorted array which make target "t" summed together and return their position as in array but 1indexed) and I tried to do it with two pointers left "l" and right "r" but I have a problem that in a problem it returns "42, 3" but it should be "3, 42" because it should return first l, which can only be smaller than r as per while loop. In C++ it worked but i dont know why it doesnt here, so my question is why does it return first bigger value even tho as stated in while loop "l" can only be smaller

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], t: int) -> List[int]:
    l = 0;
    r = len(nums)-1;
    while (l < r):
        sum = nums[l] + nums[r];
        if (sum < t): l+=1;
        elif (sum > t): r-=1;
        elif (sum == t): return { l+1, r+1}
    return { l+1, r+1};
```

Comment: `{ l+1, r+1}` is a *set* - which has no inherent ordering, when printed out you may see either value listed first.

Comment: A tuple `(l + 1, r + 1)` or an array `[l+1, r+1]` would be more appropriate here. `{l+1, r+1}` is a set, which has no ordering, and kinda shows value in a random way.

Comment: Don't even need parens for the `tuple` (since it's logically "return two values", the fact it's a `tuple` is detail). `return l + 1, r + 1` would be the standard Pythonic approach. The annotation says it's returning a `list`, but change that to `-> tuple[int, int]` (or on older Python, `-> Tuple[int, int]`) and it will agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As those in the comments have pointed out, what you are currently returning, `{ l+1, r+1}`, is a set. Sets will hash their elements and display them in a manner that may not reflect how you defined them. What you likely want instead (as indicated by the function's annotation) is a list, `[ l+1, r+1]`. Lists do not hash their elements and will preserve their order.